# How to determine format of image from page

Tags: html, css

What's the image format on this web page. 
How to determine that? I check html code and found nothing.
Thanks for your help
https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/xZbt3v_VA_d47bCCIGK6XOufya_92N1c0MDOHLmwmczS6OaKG6jfvj9wsxCxDtW8XpBB4mBrSrnPBlJ71FAEHkOLny32TgF3bYpN1ymo3hPK4g=w3840-h2160-p-k-no-nd-mv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in present you can't do that because the static( in which images are stored) path have been secured so that not anyone can access the folders in which all images and static items have been stored

Comment: Okay. But i can save this image, click "save as" and choose format what i want

Comment: yes it will just save the copy of that image in the format you want to save jpeg,png or any other